# JSON containing String and Array

Tags: json, java-me

How to convert a JSON which is a combination of String and an Array,please suggest how to do that with a code,suppose we have the following JSON

```
{"status":"true","results":[{"name":"Sudini  "},{"name":"Bimal"}]}
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/), a google library to serialize / unserialize java objects into json.

Answer (score 1):

If you're willing to use third party libraries, [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/) and [Gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) are two popular solutions that will perform data binding for you.

Answer (score 1):

If you do this in GSON:

```
public class Something{
  @SerializedName("status")
  private boolean status;
  @SerializedName("results")
  private List<Result> results;

  // accessor and mutator 

}

public class Result{
  @SerializedName("name")
  private String name;

  // accessor and mutator 
}


public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String jsonString = // your json string 

        Something obj = (Something) gson.fromJson(jsonString, Something.class);

        System.out.println(obj.getResults().get(1).getName());

    }
}
```